# Unequal variance and sample size?

Tags: variance, sample-size

What is the effect of sample size on variance? If $n$ in two groups is different, does that automatically mean variance is not equal?

Comment: The population variance has nothing to do with sample size.Sample size  affects the accuracy of the estimate of variance. There is an F test that can be used to test equality of variances based on the assumption of independent normal distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of extraordinary coincidence, the variance of two samples from the same population will be unequal even if your sample sizes are the same. That your sample sizes differ does not cause this disparity, but can exacerbate it, particularly in extreme cases. The sample variance is always biased, hence the correction usually employed.